# Session expiring at random dotnet core 3.1

Tags: iis, .net-core, asp.net-core-identity, iis-10, .net-core-3.1

We are receiving the feedback that users are randomly logged out. Some are logged out after 5 minutes other after 30 or more.

Strange thing is, we only have this on one server. There is absolutely no problem on our test- and staging server, but those are under much lower load.

We are thinking that this is related to thread shutting down in the background, causing the logoff of our users. Strang thing is, we don't receive notification about the recycling in the event logs even if we enabled it. We also haven't specified an expiration timeout in the code for the session.

What is the default expiration time in (identity) dotnet core 3.1? The docs aren't clear about this.

How can we increase the amount of threads in IIS10 (on Windows server 2016)?

Comment: Could you please tell me how you host the asp.net core application on the IIS? By using inprocess or outofprocess?  According to the asp.net core identity [sources codes](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/bfec2c14be1e65f7dd361a43950d4c848ad0cd35/src/Identity/Core/src/IdentityCookiesBuilderExtensions.cs), the default expiration time is 5 minutes.

Comment: We are using inprocess hosting